# Hosting website from home Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis

I have created a website in asp.net and deployed it on IIS. It is working fine locally. Now I want to access this site on internet. I don't want to buy domain name now. So, I am perfectly fine with the URL like this http://120.89.12.32/MyAppName/Default.aspx

Could anyone assist me knowing that if it is possible for me to host my asp.net application from my home? I am using Windows Server 2008 [R2] Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you'll need a static IP address. Most people have a dynamic one, unless they've specifically requested a static one. You may have to pay a small surcharge for static.

You can of course just access your site with whatever the current IP is, but being dynamic it will change from time to time.

Also you'll have to make sure that your router's/modem's firewall is configured to relay requests to your server. And make sure that if your ISP also provides a firewall it is configured to allow inbound requests.

Comment: He does not need a static IP. It can be done with DDNS. Just setup port forwarding on your router and you should have it.